# Data type issues when loading JSON file from GCS to Bigquery Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have JSON files in GCS and I want to import into BQ table, here is the code, simple:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
job_config.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND',
try:
    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        table_id,
        job_config=job_config,
    )
    print('Load job: %s [%s]' % (
        load_job.job_id,
        table_id
    ))
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Failed to create load job: %s' % (e))
```

The issue I got is the value of some fields in JSON files are not exactly the same data type, eg: the "Weight" field may has the value "60kg" or "60", so some records are "bad records", but I want to keep all the records, is it possible to keep them all, like set up the data type of all fields to String?

The table in BQ is created automatically since there are more than 100 fields in the JSON file, let's say if I create the table manually with all field as String, is it gonna work to keep all the records?
Thanks.

Comment: Remove this part of your code `job_config.autodetect = True`  and than you can control the field type either by creating the table or adding a `schema` object to your code

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I have to d define he type of every field. For a JSON file with more than one hundred fields, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your problem is that you have mix values in a field so the auto detect pick up the 1st record. Either clean your data or create the table in advance/add schema object to your call thus control the fields type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @TamirKlein, as you have mixed values for some columns, the auto detect will use the first row to determine what is the appropriate data type for each column.

If you want to set the schema so all columns are strings, but don’t want to hard code each line of the `bigquery.SchemaField()`, you can use the Google Cloud Storage Client to get the source file and iterate through each field of the first JSON object while appending the schema field to a list, and then use it to determine the schema configuration of the table.

You could use something like the example below:

```
bucket = client.get_bucket('[BUCKET_NAME]')
blob = storage.Blob('source.json', bucket)

json_content = blob.download_as_string().decode("utf-8")
json_blobs = json_content.split('\n')
first_object = json.loads(json_blobs[0])

schema = []
for key in first_object:
    schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(key, "STRING"))

job_config.schema = schema
```

Keep in mind that you might need to adapt this logic in case your source contains nested and repeated fields.